# Pulling images from a FTP site to Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ftp

I have the following working codes.
Column B has image names, this pulls images in the selected folder that match the names in column B and inserts them into Column A (please note, first two rows are used for my header). I've noticed that the code errors if the header in B2 is missing, then the code errors out. I would like to fix this so it will only try to find images if there is a name in Range("B3:B1002").

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Add_Images_Click()

    Const EXIT_TEXT         As String = ""
    Const NO_PICTURE_FOUND  As String = "No picture found"

    Dim picName             As String
    Dim picFullName         As String
    Dim rowIndex            As Long
    Dim lastRow             As Long
    Dim selectedFolder      As String
    Dim data()              As Variant
    Dim wks                 As Worksheet
    Dim Cell                As Range
    Dim pic                 As Picture

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    selectedFolder = GetFolder
    If Len(selectedFolder) = 0 Then GoTo ExitRoutine

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = wks.Cells(2, "B").End(xlDown).Row
    data = wks.Range(wks.Cells(1, "B"), wks.Cells(lastRow, "B")).Value2

    For rowIndex = 3 To UBound(data, 1)
        If StrComp(data(rowIndex, 1), EXIT_TEXT, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then GoTo ExitRoutine

        picName = data(rowIndex, 1)
        picFullName = selectedFolder & picName

        If Len(Dir(picFullName)) > 0 Then
            Set Cell = wks.Cells(rowIndex, "A")
            Set pic = wks.Pictures.Insert(picFullName)
            With pic
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                .Height = Cell.Height
                .Width = Cell.Width
                .Top = Cell.Top
                .Left = Cell.Left
                .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
            End With
        Else
            wks.Cells(rowIndex, "A").Value = NO_PICTURE_FOUND
        End If
    Next rowIndex

ExitRoutine:
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set pic = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Prompt:="Unable to find photo", _
           Title:="An error occured", _
           Buttons:=vbExclamation
    Resume ExitRoutine
End Sub
```

This is the Function that has the user select the folder that contains the images when the above sub is ran. I would like to modify this if possible to also work with an URL like an FTP site. So if the images are in a folder on the users pc, it will run like below, but if the images are located in a FTP location, it will still be able to pull the images.

```
Private Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim selectedFolder  As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
        .Title = "Select the folder containing the Image/PDF files."
        .Show

        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            selectedFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
            If Right$(selectedFolder, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then _
                selectedFolder = selectedFolder & Application.PathSeparator
        End If
    End With
    GetFolder = selectedFolder
End Function
```

This Sub is meant to remove all images from column A. The problem is that this works too well. It is fine when used with a normal button, but when I try using a CommandButton to have my buttons on a user form, this Sub removes the CommandButton. It also removes all comments from the sheet. I would like to either limit this to only remove images, or to quarantine the code to only look at Range("A3:A1002").

```
Private Sub Remove_Images_Click()
'Remove Images

    Dim wks         As Worksheet
    Dim shp         As Shape
    Dim picArray()  As String
    Dim index       As Integer

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Columns(1).Replace What:="No Picture Found", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlPart
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    index = 1
    For Each shp In wks.Shapes
        If shp.Type <> msoFormControl Then
            ReDim Preserve picArray(1 To index)
            picArray(index) = shp.Name
            index = index + 1
        End If
    Next shp

    wks.Shapes.Range(picArray).Delete

ExitRoutine:
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set shp = Nothing
    Erase picArray          
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Prompt:="Unable to find photo", _
           Title:="An error occured", _
           Buttons:=vbExclamation
    Resume ExitRoutine

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three main questions, probably better to separate these into different questions but I'll give it a shot.

1. Ignore row 2 in the first code block.

   Change `1` to `3` on this line: `data = wks.Range(wks.Cells(3, "B"), wks.Cells(lastRow, "B")).Value2`  This sets your data range starting at row 3 and ignores your two header rows.
2. FTP link

   This is better suited for a separate question.  Start by creating a new function that handles FTP links.  Then identify which path is in the cell, i.e. does it start with http, c://, etc...  Then call appropriate function and have it return the image to the main program.
3. Check if shape is in column A.

   Use the `TopLeftCell` attribute and see if it intersects column A

   ```
   For Each shp In wks.Shapes
     If Not Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then  '<-- New Line checks if in col A
       If shp.Type <> msoFormControl Then
         ....
   ```